# How bad is it to edit the .git folder manually?

Tags: git

Playing around with `git` I ran, on a branch `my_branch`

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

Then, I wanted to `git pull` to undo the `reset`

But origin is an online repository and, offline, `git pull` just aborts

So, I found a workaround:

- Get the hash of the tip of origin from the log
- Edit the `.git/refs/heads/origin/my_branch` and replace the hash by the one from the log

It *seems* to work but looks not so clean / unsafe to me as I am not so used to break the `.git` folder
So, that's why I am asking if it's safe

(and yes, I feel stupid to not have think that `pull` is equivalent to `fetch` + `merge`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not bad to edit branch pointers, but it's easy enough to undo a reset without it.

```
# Reset to the parent commit
git reset HEAD~1
# Reset to where HEAD was, before you last changed it
git reset 'HEAD@{1}'
```

You can use the `git reflog` command to browse these, that's where you can find `HEAD@{1}`.

In general, if you want to undo a `git reset`, you use another `git reset` to undo it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a checkout of the commit you resetted. Git will keep those around even if you don't see them so easily. Having the hash is basically all you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Arrive at a similar result to the pull with

```
git reset --hard origin/my_branch
```

Caution: `--hard` is a sharp tool. Use it with care. In this case, it will reset your local my_branch, work tree, and index to match what was in my_branch at your most recent fetch or pull. Uncommitted work may be lost.